# Is Lockheed considered an X-Man?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

In universe, is Lockheed considered by the other X-Men to also be an X-Man, or he just an occasionally useful sidekick?  Is he referred to as an X-Man in a particular comic?

Answer (score 3):

According to the the Marvel Wiki [Lockheed](http://marvel.com/universe/Lockheed) is considered an X-man as well as one of the founding members of Excalibur. After helping the X-men to defeat the Brood on Lockheed's home planet, Flock, Lockheed followed Kitty back to earth and then went on to help the X-Men destroy an alien nest below the mansion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is he referred to as an X-Man by other X-Men at any point?

Comment: I have never read anywhere one of the characters listing him amongst the team but I have been out of comics for about a decade.  The Marvel Wiki does list that his group affiliation does lie with the X-men and the team guide from the end of Wolverine and the X-men #1 puts his picture next to Kitty's at the Jean Grey School.

Comment: I love that he is considered an X-Man, he's definitely put in his share of hard work for the team over the years.